# Assembler loaded string to decimal notation

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to write a program that will change the loaded string to decimal notation and write on console what we received, now in this code only echo works, how to move in memory to change string we received?

```
.align 32

SYSEXIT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
STDOUT = 1
STDIN =0
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

.data

    bufor: .space 1000
    bufor_len = 10
    num: .int =10
    numm: .int =1


.text

    text: .ascii "Podaj ciag znakow"
    text_len = . - text

.global _start
_start:

    mov $SYSWRITE, %eax
    mov $STDOUT, %ebx
    mov $text, %ecx
    mov $text_len, %edx
    int $0x80

    mov $SYSREAD, %eax
    mov $STDIN, %ebx
    mov $bufor, %ecx
    mov $bufor_len, %edx
    int $0x80


ety_1:
    mov $bufor, %eax
    mov $al, %ecx
    imul $num, %ecx
ety_2:

    shr $numm, %eax
    mov $al, %ebx
    imul $num, %ebx
    add %ebx, %eax
    cmp %al,lf
    jne ety_2

    int $0x80

    mov $SYSWRITE, %eax
    mov $STDOUT, %ebx
    mov $bufor, %ecx
    mov $bufor_len, %edx
    int $0x80

    mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
    mov $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Comment: _"I need to write a program that will change the loaded string to decimal notation"_. What do you intend to change it _from_?

Comment: ASCII, from aaa i should get 65 65 65

Comment: If you divide, say, 65 by 10, you'll get a quotient of 6, and a remainder of 5. If you add the ASCII code for `'0'` to both of these, then you'll have the characters for `'6'` and `'5'`, which you can then output.

Answer (score 0):

Your characters are already in ASCII format. What you're looking for is just a way to output them differently.

In general, to print a numeric representation of a number, you need to extract the individual digits (which, for a decimal representation, can be done by repeatedly dividing by 10 and examining the remainder) and add the ASCII code for `'0'` to them, to give you the printable characters. Then you just output the printable characters.

Here's a fairly crude way of doing it in nasm format x86_64 assembly, taking advantage of the fact that printable ASCII characters can be represented in no less than two, and no more than three, decimal digits:

```
global _start

STDIN           equ     0
STDOUT          equ     1
STDERR          equ     2

SYSCALL_READ    equ     0
SYSCALL_WRITE   equ     1
SYSCALL_EXIT    equ     60

ASCII_ZERO      equ     0x30
ASCII_SPACE     equ     0x20


        section .rodata

src     db      'Podaj ciag znajow', 0x00       ;  String to convert
newline db      0x0a, 0x00                      ;  String for print_newline


        section .data

ach     db      'XXX ', 0x00                    ;  String for print_ascii


        section .text

;  Exits with success code.

exit_success:
        mov     rax, SYSCALL_EXIT
        mov     rdi, 0
        syscall


;  Calculates length of null-terminated string.
;  Arg 1 - address of string.
;  Returns - length of string.

string_length:
        push    rbp                     ;  Set up stack
        mov     rbp, rsp

        mov     rax, -1                 ;  Set character count to -1
        xor     rdx, rdx                ;  Zero register for character

.slloop:
        inc     rax                     ;  Increment character count
        mov     dl, BYTE [rdi+rax]      ;  Load character to dl
        cmp     dl, 0                   ;  If it's not the null character...
        jne     .slloop                 ;  ...keep counting.

        leave                           ;  Return character count
        ret


;  Outputs a null-terminated string to standard output.
;  Arg 1 - address of string.
;  No return value.

put_string:
        push    rbp                     ;  Set up stack
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16

        mov     [rbp-16], rdi           ;  Save address prior to func call

        call    string_length           ;  Get length of string
        mov     rdi, STDOUT             ;  First arg to write syscall
        mov     rsi, [rbp-16]           ;  Restore address to second arg
        mov     rdx, rax                ;  Third arg to write syscall
        mov     rax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ;  Load system call number
        syscall                         ;  Make system call

        leave                           ;  Return
        ret


;  Prints a numeric representation of a character's ASCII code.
;  Arg 1 - the character.
;  No return value.

print_ascii:
        push    rbp                     ;  Set up stack
        mov     rbp, rsp

        mov     rax, rdi                ;  Move character to rax
        mov     rcx, 10                 ;  Load rcx with divisor

        ;  Extract least significant digit

        xor     rdx, rdx                ;  Zero high-order bits for idiv
        idiv    rcx                     ;  Divide character by ten
        add     rdx, ASCII_ZERO         ;  Add '0' to remainder
        mov     BYTE [ach+2], dl        ;  Write third digit to string

        ;  Extract two most significant digits from quotient

        xor     rdx, rdx                ;  Zero high-order bits for idiv
        idiv    rcx                     ;  Divide by ten
        add     rax, ASCII_ZERO         ;  Add '0' to new quotient
        add     rdx, ASCII_ZERO         ;  Add '0' to new remainder

        ;  Write digits to string and print

        mov     BYTE [ach], al          ;  Write first digit to string
        mov     BYTE [ach+1], dl        ;  Write second digit to string

        lea     rdi, [ach]              ;  Load address of string
        lea     rsi, [ach+1]            ;  Prepare for conditional move
        cmp     rax, ASCII_ZERO         ;  If most significant digit is zero...
        cmove   rdi, rsi                ;  ...don't print it
        call    put_string              ;  Print ASCII representation

        leave                           ;  Return
        ret


;  Prints a newline
;  No arguments, no return value.

print_newline:
        push    rbp                     ;  Set up stack
        mov     rbp, rsp

        lea     rdi, [newline]          ;  Load address of newline string
        call    put_string              ;  Print it

        leave                           ;  Return
        ret


;  Entry point

_start:
        mov     rbp, rsp                ;  Set up stack
        sub     rsp, 16                 ;  Set up some local storage
        lea     rdi, [src]              ;  Load address of string

        call    put_string              ;  Print plain string first
        call    print_newline           ;  For tidy output
        lea     rdi, [src]              ;  Reload address after func call

.mainloop:
        movsx   rax, BYTE [rdi]         ;  Move a byte to rax
        cmp     rax, 0                  ;  If it's zero...
        je      .loopdone               ;  ...then we're done.

        mov     [rbp-16], rdi           ;  Save current string address
        mov     rdi, rax                ;  Pass character to function
        call    print_ascii             ;  Print representation of character
        mov     rdi, [rbp-16]           ;  Restore current string address
        inc     rdi                     ;  Increment current string address
        jmp     .mainloop               ;  Loop again

.loopdone:
        call    print_newline           ;  For tidy output
        call    exit_success            ;  Exit
```

with output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/asm/scratch$ nasm -f elf64 -o stoa.o stoa.asm
paul@thoth:~/src/asm/scratch$ ld -o stoa stoa.o
paul@thoth:~/src/asm/scratch$ ./stoa
Podaj ciag znajow
80 111 100 97 106 32 99 105 97 103 32 122 110 97 106 111 119 
paul@thoth:~/src/asm/scratch$
```

Obviously if you want to actually modify the original string, you'll have to have a lot more space for it, since you can count on the length increasing by between 2 and 3 times, to make room for all the digits, before even including any spaces.